# Universal Authentication for Auth0 doesn't allow logout

Tags: java, android, auth0

I am writing an Android app using Auth0 authentication. I use the universal login to allow the user to log in. However, the issue is that once a user has logged in, I can't seem to find a way to log out. If I used the `CredentialsManager.clearCredentials()` option, then the universal login still auto-logs me in. Is there a way to tell the universal login to "force" a login?

```
WebAuthProvider.init(account)
            .withScope("openid profile email")
            .withScheme("android")
            .start(this, new AuthCallback() {
```

Comment: Feel free to raise the issue in auth0 community portal for more traction. Also additionally you can follow the steps mentioned here- https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force the user to login again by passing `login` as value for `prompt` to `/authorize`. You can do this with `withParameters()`. [Source code](https://github.com/auth0/Auth0.Android/blob/master/auth0/src/main/java/com/auth0/android/provider/WebAuthProvider.java#L235).

Authentication API is OIDC compliant so you can take a look at the documentation for `prompt` [here](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest).

**EDIT:**

To truely logout the user by removing the session at Auth0 as well, is to redirect user to the logout endpoint https://YOUR_DOMAIN/v2/logout. In browsers and Javascript, this would be the equivalent of window.location.url = https://YOUR_DOMAIN/v2/logout

Comment: I thought it might have something to do with the parameters, but that still doens't seem to be working :/ Same behavior as before.

Comment: hmmm you might be on a new tenant that has the "Seamless SSO" behaviour enabled by default, see https://auth0.com/docs/sso/current/setup#addendum-sso-configuration-for-legacy-tenants

Comment: To truely logout the user by removing the session at Auth0 as well, is to redirect user to the [logout](https://auth0.com/docs/logout) endpoint `https://YOUR_DOMAIN/v2/logout`. In browsers and Javascript, this would be the equivalent of `window.location.url = https://YOUR_DOMAIN/v2/logout`

Comment: It looks like your last comment worked - if you change the answer to that, I'll accept it :) I'm still not totally satisfied with opening the browser to log out - I'll tinker with getting a WebView to work, but for now, it's a good workaround. Thanks!

Comment: @ShayanMemari I am unable to redirect the User back to returnTo page(via server side). Is redirection has to be done from Front-End?